# Display popups with leaflet ( large dataset )

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Im using Leaflet & Geojson-vt to visualize a large dataset (GeoJSON with 70,000 polylines features)

Is there any way to show smoothly a popup (it contains the polyline data) on click event on one of the multiple polylines ?

I am using geojson-vt and the example from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/c67e5551b21c68dc8299) to add the tiles to the leaflet map.

i tried this

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function(e) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.NUMERO);
    });
}

L.geoJson($scope.dataOfFile.data, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

but the map keep freezing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understanding... That example draws a canvas layer from vector tiles, this has no interaction method. If it were polygons you could use point in polygon from the original data. Since it's lines you may want to experiment with the almost over plugin using 0 weight (transparent) lines.

Comment: I want to add a click to show popup with data for each feature (70 000 popups) , the code is working but the map freeze, is there any way to do that smoothly ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with popups on Markers. If I added the popup before the marker was added to the map then the map would briefly freeze when all the markers were added to the map.

So instead I added the Markers to the map first. I maintained an array of all the markers then added the popups afterwards to each marker and I no longer experienced the map locking up.